# C++ Recursive Print Function for IntStack

Tags: c++, recursion

I've been tasked with creating a print function that uses recursion to print the data of a singly linked list (stack). Here is my code thus far:

IntStack.h

```
#include <iostream>

struct NodeType
{
    int data;
    NodeType *next;
};

class IntStack
{
private:
    NodeType root;
    int count;
public:
    IntStack(void);
    ~IntStack(void);

    void push(int);
    int pop(void);
    bool isEmpty(void);
    void print(NodeType&);
    int getSize() const;
    NodeType* getRoot();
};
```

IntStack.cpp

```
#include "IntStack.h"

IntStack::IntStack()
{
    count = 0;
}

IntStack::~IntStack()
{

}

void IntStack::push(int num)
{
    NodeType newNode;
    newNode.data = num;

    newNode.next = &root;
    root = newNode;

    ++count;
}

int IntStack::pop(void)
{
    // get root data
    // set root equal to root.next
    int num = root.data;
    root = *root.next;
    --count;
    return num;
}

bool IntStack::isEmpty(void)
{
    return (count == 0);
}

void print(NodeType *node)
{
    if (node->next != NULL) {
        std::cout << node->data << " " << std::endl;
        print(node->next);
    }
}

NodeType* IntStack::getRoot()
{
    return &root;
}

int IntStack::getSize() const
{
    return count;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntStack.h"

int main()
{
    IntStack stack;
    stack.push(7);
    stack.push(10);
    stack.push(13);
    stack.push(43);
    stack.push(23);
    stack.push(5);
    stack.push(32);
    stack.push(8);

    std::cout << stack.getSize() << " item(s) in the stack." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Pop item off stack: " << stack.pop() << std::endl;
    std::cout << stack.getSize() << " item(s) in the stack." << std::endl;

    stack.print(stack.getRoot());

    return 0;
}
```

I'm receiving an error on the stack.print(stack.getRoot()) function in main.cpp:

> main.cpp:28:17: Non-const lvalue reference to type 'NodeType' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'NodeType *'

Obviously, I'm not sending a pointer to the function, but I've tried various ways to send the root node with no luck. Any information on how I should proceed is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The error is about line 28 in your `main.cpp` source file, but that file doesn't have 28 lines as you show it to us. Please show the proper file, or the correct error message.

Comment: Also, you are doing lots of other stuff wrong, like overwriting the `root` field every time you push a value: When you push a value, you set the new nodes `next` pointer to point to `root`, but then you overwrite `root` so the `root->next` will point to `root`. The variable `root` should be a pointer, and you should allocate new `NodeType` using `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should be allocating your nodes on the Heap not on the Stack. In short for something to be Heap allocated rather than Stack allocated, you have to use the "new" keyword.

```
// node1 is stack allocated
NodeType node1;

// node2 is heap allocated
NodeType *node2 = new NodeType;
```

Reason being, anything allocated to the stack expires(is deleted) when the function returns. In your case, you need to keep your nodes around beyond the end of the function.

so change `NodeType root;` to `NodeType *root;` and set root to NULL in the constructor.

You will have to alter your push function, among others, to get your program to work now.

```
void IntStack::push(int num)
{
    NodeType *newNode = new NodeType; // heap allocated now
    newNode->data = num; // use appropriate dereferencing operator "->"

    newNode->next = root; // root is now a pointer

    root = newNode;

    ++count;
}
```

to delete a node, you would do the reverse

```
int IntStack::pop(void)
{
    int num = root->data;

    NodeType *tmp = root; // don't lose the pointer
    root = root->next;
    delete tmp; // heap allocated memory must be freed if it is allocated

    --count;

    return num;
}
```

<strike>Adding a constructor to NodeType to set the variable next to NULL would also be a good idea, because</strike> when it comes to recursively printing the nodes, you will have to know when you have reached the last node, which will be indicated by the "next" pointer being NULL.

**edit:**
I crossed out a line above. Since you initialize root to NULL, and `next` always gets set to the value of root, `NodeType` shouldn't need a constructor. But, the condition in your print function should be `if (node != NULL)` instead of `if (node->next != NULL)`. Consider the case where you have 0 or 1 node.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `void print(NodeType&);` in your header file, instead of using the pointer version like in your .cpp file. Change the `&` to a `*` and it will work.

(Really odd pattern by the way)

Comment: I thought it was strange too for print to even have a parameter since it is a stack... with this implementation, you could hold a reference to the middle of the stack and then print from the middle to the bottom while skipping the contents that have more recently been added to the stack... o.O

Comment: Yep; it does work though and it's not related to the question itself so.. up to him!

Answer (score 0):

Your prototypes don't match your function use.

```
void print(NodeType&)
```

While in your implementation file you have the following

```
void print(NodeType *node)
```

I believe you are wanting to use the NodeType* one, so change it in your headerfile to reflect that.

Another line I saw that I found confusing was the print line within the print function.

```
std::cout << node->data << " " << std::endl;
```

Why are you printing a newline after EACH print? I recommend changing it to removing the `endl` print.